# @stripe/stripe-react-native payment-sheet (Save card data)

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, stripe-apps

[image: stripe payment sheet]

i am trying to integrate payment sheet with customer(stripe customer id) and save card option(as shown in image) and the customer was linked with payment but **Save this card for future powdur payments** option was not showing. i can't understand why that's not showing? if any buddy have idea about this then pls tell..

server-side Code

***createCustomer***

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event.arguments));
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    name: event.arguments?.input?.name,
    email: event.arguments.input?.email,
    payment_method: 'pm_card_visa',
    invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: 'pm_card_visa',
    },
  });
  console.log('Customer Data', JSON.stringify(customer));
  return {
    id: customer.id ?? 'Default',
  };
};
```

***createPaymentIntent***

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('Event', JSON.stringify(event.arguments.input));
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({ ...event.arguments.input });
    console.log(paymentIntent.client_secret);
    return {
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    return {
      error: error.message,
    };
  }
};

/** createIntent data
 * description: 'Software development services',
    customer: customerId,
    shipping: {
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      address: {
        line1: '510 Townsend St',
        postal_code: '98140',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
      },
    },
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
 */
```

Comment: Could you please share the parameters you are passing when creating the PaymentIntent ? You need to make sure that you are passing setup_future_usage: off_session 

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#:~:text=Creates%20a%20PaymentIntent,and%20automatic_payment_methods%20enabled

Comment: I am passed data which is shown as comment in below createPaymentIntent function.

Comment: And i also tried setup_future_usage: off_session / on_session but that doesn't  works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the customerId while initializing the PaymentSheet in your frontend so that the created PaymentMethod will be attached to a customer and it can be used for future payments[1]

```
const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
      customerId: customer,
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent,
});
```

​​[1] [https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#:~:text=To%20set%20up%20a%20payment%20method%20for%20future%20payments%2C%20it%20must%20be%20attached%20to%20a%20Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#:%7E:text=To%20set%20up%20a%20payment%20method%20for%20future%20payments%2C%20it%20must%20be%20attached%20to%20a%20Customer)